# Why are pads not connected all way around in copper filled areas?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, high-current, easyeda

I'm designing a circuit that will supposedly pass 30A continuous, I assumed the best I can do to prevent tracks from burning is just use copper fill so that essentially the whole area is my high current track, and just put other components on the edges.

Zooming in though I see that there are small pockets around the pad that are not connected to the copper fill. I can manually add copper shapes on top to fill it but I figured it must be there for a reason, so I searched for it but lacking the terminology I didn't find anything useful.

Here you can see the issue on pad #87

[image]

What are these pockets for and should I fill them manually to make the connection all way around the circle?

Comment: They're thermal reliefs to aid soldering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's for thermal relief.

If you solder manually, without the gaps the heat transfers efficiently from the pad to the copper plane so it takes a lot of heat from the soldering iron and a lot of time to make the temperature rise enough for the solder to melt.

With the gaps, only a limited amount of heat transfers from pad to plane, and it takes less heat from soldering iron, and the pad temperature rises faster to solder melting temperature.

Comment: So it's better to fill them, I'll only solder once, high current will travel *forever* :)

Comment: @php_nub_qq - Without thermal reliefs you may not be able to get a good solder joint.